# how to prevent R sweave from printing for loop function

Tags: r, for-loop, sweave

I used

echo=TRUE, results=hide

But the R sweave prints out the function of the for loop as well which is more than 3 pages. How can I stop R sweave from printing the function of the for loop and only print out the for {} code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be

`echo=FALSE, results=hide`

or

`echo=FALSE, results='hide'`

If you use `echo=TRUE`, you are asking `sweave` to print your code.